# Minimize windows without them going black and white

Tags: kubuntu, kde, window-manager, minimize, plasma

I recently updated to KDE 4.10. Now when I minimize windows, the task manager shows them being black and white. I find this very annoying since I tend to find windows primarily based on colors, not based on the shape of their icon. It takes me usually at least twice as long to find the window I'm looking for now because of this. Is there any way to switch it back to previous behavior where minimized windows would still have color in the task manager?

This is what it looks like now. Firefox is minimized while the System settings window is not. It's usually quite easy to spot a bright orange and blue icon. Not so here:

[image: KDE 4.10 task manager ugliness]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to go to:

> System Settings > Application Appearance > Icons > Advanced

And under `All Icons` remove the effect for the `Disabled` icon.

---

**Edit**

Here's the respective KDE bug report https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=311991

Comment: Thanks a pile, that was one thing driving me nuts after switching to Debian Jessie with KDE Plasma!

Answer (score 1):

**Settings**

The default KDE task manager has filter setting - with the "Only show tasks that are minimized" the KDE 4.10 task manager will show the icons with the colors.

[image]

**There are other task managers**

Earlier: [Modify KDE Desktop theme](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254825/modify-kde-desktop-theme)

The other task managers don't paint the minimized application icons grey.

[image]

Or use the default task manager filters

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I do not want to use the Icon Only or Smooth task managers and it would aggravate me beyond belief to have the task manager only show minimized windows. I have posted my own answer below which actually "solves" the problem.