# KDE taskbar questions

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde4

1) How can I set minimized apps' names on taskbar NOT to be gray? (ie they are always black)

2) How can I make taskbar not transparent in default theme? But other way than turning all desktops effects off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1**

A1/Askubuntu: [Minimize windows without them going black and white](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261247/minimize-windows-without-them-going-black-and-white)

If you only want to change the text color: KDE system settings > Workspace Appearance > Desktop Theme > Details > Color Scheme

[image]

**Q2**

A2/Askubuntu: [How to change color/transparency of all desktop panels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70694/how-to-change-color-transparency-of-all-desktop-panels/)

Comment: The question should marked as duplicate of both, not answered.